# Modelling an Ensemble of five transformers

Tags: nlp, classification, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to build a ensemble model for my text classification task using 5 transformer architecture. But due to not being fluent in python OOP concept i have to seek out for help. So far my model is the following:

```
class BERTClassA(torch.nn.Module):
  def init(self):
    super(BERTClassA, self).init()
    self.l1 = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    self.pre_classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 768)
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(.3)
  
  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    output_1 = self.l1(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    hidden_state = output_1[0]
    pooler = hidden_state[:, 0]
    pooler = self.pre_classifier(pooler)
    pooler = torch.nn.ReLU()(pooler)
    output = self.dropout(pooler)
    return output

class BERTClassB(torch.nn.Module):
  def init(self):
    super(BERTClassB, self).init()
    self.l2 = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
    self.pre_classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 768)
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(.3)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    output_2 = self.l2(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    hidden_state = output_2[0]
    pooler = hidden_state[:, 0]
    pooler = self.pre_classifier(pooler)
    pooler = torch.nn.ReLU()(pooler)
    output = self.dropout(pooler)
    return output

class BERTClassC(torch.nn.Module):
  def init(self):
    super(BERTClassC, self).init()
    self.l3 = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', num_labels = 2)
    self.pre_classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 768)
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(.3)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    output_3 = self.l3(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    hidden_state = output_3[0]
    pooler = hidden_state[:, 0]
    pooler = self.pre_classifier(pooler)
    pooler = torch.nn.ReLU()(pooler)
    output = self.dropout(pooler)
    return output


class BERTClassD(torch.nn.Module):
  def init(self):
    super(BERTClassD, self).init()
    self.l4 = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased',output_hidden_states=True)
    self.pre_classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 768)
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(.3)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    output_4 = self.l4(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    hidden_state = output_4[0]
    pooler = hidden_state[:, 0]
    pooler = self.pre_classifier(pooler)
    pooler = torch.nn.ReLU()(pooler)
    output = self.dropout(pooler)
    return output




class BERTClassE(torch.nn.Module):
  def init(self):
    super(BERTClassE, self).init()
    self.l5 = ElectraForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('google/electra-base-discriminator',num_labels=2,return_dict= True)
    self.pre_classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 768)
    self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(.3)

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
    output_5 = self.l5(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    hidden_state = output_5[0]
    pooler = hidden_state[:, 0]
    pooler = self.pre_classifier(pooler)
    pooler = torch.nn.ReLU()(pooler)
    output = self.dropout(pooler)
    return output
```

I want to combine all the classes above with the following class:

```
class MyEnsemble(torch.nn.Module):
  def init(self, modelA, modelB,modelC,modelD,modelE):
    super(MyEnsemble, self).init()
    self.modelA = modelA
    self.modelB = modelB
    self.modelC= modelC
    self.modelD= modelD
    self.modelE= modelE
    self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(768, 2)
  def forward(self, x1, x2,x3,x4,x5):
    x1 = self.modelA(x1)
    x2 = self.modelB(x2)
    x3 = self.modelC(x3)
    x4 = self.modelD(x4)
    x5 = self.modelE(x5)
    x = torch.cat((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), dim=1)
    x = self.classifier(F.relu(x))
    return x
```

Problem is when i run the training epoch, i get the following error:

forward() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'x3', 'x4', and 'x5'

my Training epoch function is as follows:

```
def train_epoch(
  model, 
  data_loader, 
  loss_fn, 
  optimizer, 
  device, 
  scheduler, 
  n_examples
):
  model = model.train()

  losses = []
  correct_predictions = 0


  for d in data_loader:
    input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
    attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
    targets = d["targets"].to(device)

    outputs = model(
      input_ids,
      attention_mask
    )

    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)

    correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)
    losses.append(loss.item())

    loss.backward()
    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

  return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)
```

I ran the following before calling the MyEnsemble() class:

```
modelA = BERTClassA()
modelB = BERTClassB()
modelC = BERTClassC()
modelD = BERTClassD()
modelE = BERTClassE()
```

Finally the model as :

```
model = MyEnsemble()
model.to(device)
```

Do you spot any problem in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling your `MyEnsemble` function with only two arguments (quote from your code):

```py
outputs = model(
  input_ids,
  attention_mask
)
```

You will have to re-write your `forward()` function of the ensemble in such a way, that you arrange/split the desired inputs between models, and feed them correctly.

Comment: What should be the correct way to write the MyEnsemble class? I am struggling with this.

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to be doing. Should each model in the ensemble get the same inputs, or give chunks of text to each network? With the current information given, it is unclear what solution is expected.

Comment: I will be chunking my dataset with batch size =32, i created a dataloader and each time i want my ensemble class to process each batch and give me an output. I dont know how the classes actually work in python. I am passing Model_A(), Model_B().....Model_E() to my Ensemble class but i am not sure if i am correct with the syntax. I have rewritten the whole code. Should i share it here?

Comment: Since this is unrelated to the problem stated above, I suggest you open a new question with the *expected output* and *exemplary input*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035953/how-to-write-an-ensemble-model-class , Please have a look. Thank You.